# How to specify path in .config file relative to the file?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

An app I use interprets a .NET `.config` file. I added a line specifying the path to a certificate it needs

```
<add key="Certificate" value="..\certificate.abc"/>
```

However, I found the app only works when run from the exact folder its `.exe` and `.config` reside. If run from another folder, it fails, because it looks for the certificate at `../` expanded *relative to the working directory*.

What should I write in the config file, to make sure the path is `..\certificate.abc` expanded *relative to the config file* rather the working directory?

I can't change the app (it's not mine), I can only change the config file.

Comment: If this is just a key you've added then you'd do that in code once you read the key value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using the tilde

```
value="~/certificate.abc"
```

Comment: Where did you learn about the tilde? I can't find this documented.

Comment: @ColonelPanic ~ represents the home folder in *nix O. S. This is not properly documented indeed.

Answer (score 3):

In visual studio 2015, the "~" keyword has no longer worked.
You can now use :

```
value="folder\subfoler"
```

"folder" has the same level with .exe file

Comment: How can we refer to a location in a parent directory then?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change this just by changing the config file. Unless you use an absolute path.

If you can change the application ...

If this is an asp.net application, then use `Server.MapPath`. If it's a Windows app, you need to get the directory of the executing application and combine that with the relative path in your config file.

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will give you the path to the .EXE file. You can then call [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to combine your relative path with the application's path.

Answer (score 1):

`..\` goes up a folder level. Repeat as many times as needed e.g. `..\..\` to get to your bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you need set file name. Folder where all files you know (if folder can be canged  - set folder without ../)

And where you need use path - combine current location of application(can be got in runtime ) and key from settings

or use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/[PARTH_TO_FILE]") '
```

Comment: You don't need to copy other peoples answers by editing your answers.

Answer (score 0):

you config file may lie on other location then the executing file. as you mantion executing path i understand this is the desktop based application so here you go what you can do like this.

in Config.

```
 <setting name="FilePath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>AppPath\MyFile.abc</value>
    </setting>
```

and to retrive this.

```
   var path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];

            if  (path !=null && path.Contains("AppPath"))
            {

                var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
                    path.Replace("AppPath", string.Empty).ToString());

                Console.WriteLine(filepath);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use "../" Before your file path where you want to put your logs

If you are using below code

ErrorLog folder will be created in your bin\Debug\net5.0