# How to get the base directory path in App.config?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

From app.config I want to dynamically get the base directory path where project exe is present. Is that possible?

For example, in C# code we can write the following to get the path.
`string executablePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Is there any way to get this path in app.config?

`<add key="AssemblyPath" value="????" />` what to write in value? since it will be varied from user to user how to get it dynamically?
and then in the project, we want to use this as

`string executablePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssemblyPath"];`

I checked many posts on StackOverflow flow but did not get this particular answer.

Comment: What is the value of setting the path in the config file just to later use it in code when could just call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`? The config file is not executing anything it's only xml, you would have to run the app and have it write to the config file.

Comment: @JSteward So what we are writing is, we are downloading pdf files and for every environment staging/dev/prod, we want to have the flexibility to handle where we save this files. The default location we want to keep it as assembly path. So if staging environment wants to change the path they should be able to do so by changing staging_app.config. That's the reason we want to have this in config.file

Comment: @JSteward Is this explanation okay to remove negative mark?

Comment: The down vote wasn't me. But one of the answers already provided ought to get you want you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do instead is have something like

```
<add key="AssemblyPath" value="!!BASE_DIRECTORY!!" />
```

and then in your code

```
var assemblyPathConfigEntry = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssemblyPath"];
string pathToUse;
switch(assemblyPathConfigEntry) 
{
    case "!!BASE_DIRECTORY!!":
        pathToUse = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        break;
    default:
        pathToUse = assemblyPathConfigEntry;
        break;
}  

return pathToUse;
```

In this case if you put `!!BASE_DIRECTORY!!` as a value, it will get the current base directory, otherwise it will just use the path you put in there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the Tilde like in this answer :
[How to specify path in .config file relative to the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168154/how-to-specify-path-in-config-file-relative-to-the-file)

`<add key="AssemblyPath" value="~/YourDirectoryYouWantToAccess">`

Answer (score 0):

`appSettings` section is a simple representation of a collection of associated String keys and String values that can be accessed either with the key or with the index. It is not exexuting any code on the string, the app must be loaded to get the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`.

Answer (score 0):

Here how

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Another way is

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

Comment: Tho the answer is old...It is really not an answer....The question is how to achieve this in app.Config(xml) not in code-behind(cs)

Comment: App.config can have values represented in string (json or xml) , you can not execute any code in app.config , hope you getting what everyone trying to say here

Comment: What do you even mean ? The question clearly states to achieve it from app.settings..... The solution is very very easy

Comment: Have you achieved the solution ?

Comment: Are you writing path value in app.config ?

Comment: i will answer this question within a mintue(tho i didnt write the base path in app.config but i did a workaround)

Comment: @zackraiyan if you have a solution than please post it so others can benefit it in future

Comment: Checkout my answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution is somewhat easy.Create your `Key` in `App.config` like this :(in my case , it was a connection string)

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\mydatabase.mdb;Initial Catalog=OmidPayamak;Integrated Security=True"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Then from your code behind, do the following :

```
 var currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
 var basePath = currentDomain.BaseDirectory;
 currentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", basePath+"\\Data");

 //now the value of your connection string's Data Source would be like this :

 //myAppPath\Data\Mydatabase.mdb
```

Hope this helps to solve the issue !

Comment: BaseDirectory is not a method, it is a property. Pleas fix the code.

Comment: @Mary , fix what ?? the code is fine...Debug it before complaining -_-

Comment: @Mary , i know it's a property, when did i even mention it's a method ?

Comment: The code is not fine if it needs debugging. It will not compile as presented. I told you exactly what is wrong. but there is an additional error in the last line.

Comment: Go back and study the basics of C#. How do you invoke a method in C#?

Comment: @Mary , this is not me bargaining without knowing..... Debug it first...and why does it even matter if i pass `.BaseDirectory` value to a property ?? Try the code first please and then comment....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172443/discussion-between-zack-raiyan-and-mary).

Answer (score 0):

In .Net/.Net Core,
you can make the web.config/appsetting.json to get a copy in the output directory.
Here are the steps:
1. Go to properties of the file
2. In option "Copy to Output Directory", make it as "Copy Always"(it will be "Do not copy" as default).

After that, you can use the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` to get the path 
It will be the bin folder path of the project, but it's ok as the config file will be present in the bin folder.

You can also use `Environment.CurrentDirectory();`

For best practice set the path as an environment variable.