# How to add Relative path to app config file?

Tags: c#, database, windows, desktop-application, relative-path

I have the following windows form c# application .. I just want to add a relative path to app.config file . to make my app connect to the database right:
here's the connection string:



[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irhll.png)

Comment: connection string is as following :<connectionStrings>
   <add name="connstring" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=F:\Content_Creator\NewFolder1\Client.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify path in .config file relative to the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168154/how-to-specify-path-in-config-file-relative-to-the-file)

Comment: Instead of adding "connection string" as comment, edit your own question and add there for more completeness.